# Two programming problems in C for Structured of Data

Tags: c, function

1. First problem:

> Create a function called triangles that prints an upside down right triangle
>        (composed of *'s) that starts out n stars wide and decreases down to one star then goes back up to n stars. DO NOT MODIFY below by the Instructor.
>       Example input/output:
>
> ```
> ./p3 4
>  ****
>  ***
>  **
>  *
>  **
>  ***
>  ****
> ```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("usage: h4 <number>\n");
        return 1;
    }
    triangles(atoi(argv[1]));

    return 0;
}
```

2. Second problem:

> Do not modify main below. Write the function pyramid that takes an
>   integer
>       and outputs a pyramid constructed of asterisks(*) that is that
>       of rows high.
>
> ```
> input/output:
> ./p4 4
>    *
>   ***
>  *****
> *******
> ```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void pyramid (int a) {
/* ???? */
}

int row = argc;

int i, j, row;
for(i=row; i>=1; --i) {
    for(j=1; j<=i; ++j) {
        printf("%d ",j);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
return 0;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) //Do not modify
{
    if (argc < 2) //Do not modify
    {
        printf ("usage: h4 <number>\n");//Do not modify
        return 1;//Do not modify
    }
    pyramid(atoi (argv[1]));//Do not modify

    return 0;
}
```

I know the basic of Javascript and C programming, but I am not sure how to start with function from `triangles(atoi(argv[1]));` or `pyramid(atoi (argv[1]));` Nobody tell me about this before?? The help is more appreciated so I can study what it looks like. Thank you.

Comment: Tell or show what you tried

Comment: There are many questions in the C tag on SO about printing variations on the theme of pyramids.  You should look at them and get ideas.  Also, it is generally better to ask two separate questions which can each get its own set of answers, rather than combine them into one.

Comment: As you are new to SO here is something you need to know: **Never make significant changes to your question once an answer has been posted** If someone reads your question as it is now and then reads my answer, they will think that the answer is all wrong because they don't see your original question. I'll rollback the question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to do your homework but here is a **hint** for your first problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void triangles(int n)
{
  int t;

  // Print first half
  t = n;
  while(t)
    {
      for(int i=0; i<t; ++i) printf("*");
      printf("\n");
      --t;
    }

  // Print second half
  t = 2;
  // ... add code here
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  if (argc < 2)
    {
      printf("usage: h4 <number>\n");
      return 1;
    }
  triangles(atoi(argv[1]));

  return 0;
 }
```

./p3 4 will give:

```
****
***
**
*
```

As you can see it printed the first half of the triangle. Using the same principle, you can now add code for printing the second half.

Comment: {
      for(int i=0; i<t; --i) printf("*");
      printf("\n");
      ++t;
    }

Comment: @StartProgrammer not exactly but close... try it and see what it does... then you'll soon see the problem and get your homework done

Comment: Got it figured out.